# Change opacity of a particular div, on mouse hover, and add a text label

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Question is: Change opacity of a particular div, on mouse hover, and add a text label, to display which div is being hovered and changed opacity.

My Solution so far- I have changed the opacity, but for all the divs(HISTOGRAM, basically).

Problem- Want to change for a particular div, on HOVER.

**HTML File**

```
<head>
    <title>Statistical Histograms</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxes.css">
    <!-- <script src="alter.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="box.js"></script>
    <form>
     Number:<input type="text" id="number"/><br>
     <input type="button" id="button1" value="Draw" onClick="draw()"/><br>
     <input type="button" id="button2" value="Change Color" onClick="color()"/><br>
     <div id="histContainer" style="position: relative;"> </div>
      <!-- <input type="button" id="color_change" style="float: right;" value="Change Color" /> -->

</body>
```

**JavaScript File**

```
function draw() 
{
    var nums = document.getElementById("number").value.split(",");
    console.log(nums);
    var w = 40;
    var factor = 20;
    var n_max =  Math.max.apply(parseInt, nums);
        var h_max = factor * n_max;
        console.log("h max is " + h_max);
        console.log("n max is " + n_max);
    //var h_max = Math.max(h);
    //var a = parseInt(nums);
    //var create = document.getElementById("shape");
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= nums.length ; i++)
    {
        //var x = parseInt(nums[i]);

        //var final_width = w / x;
        var x_cor = (i+1) * w;
        //var y_cor = i * w * 0.5;
        var h = factor * nums[i];
        console.log(x_cor);
        console.log(h);
        //console.log(h_max);   



        var change = document.getElementById("histContainer");
        //change.className = 'myClass';
        var bar = document.createElement("div");
        bar.className = 'myClass';
        //var c_change = document.createElement("div2");
        //change.appendChild(c_change);
        change.appendChild(bar);

        console.log(change);
        //change.style.x.value = x_cor;
        //change.style.y.value = y_cor;
        bar.style.position = "absolute";
        bar.style.top = (h_max - h) + "px";
        //bar.style.transform = "rotate(-1deg)"
        bar.style.left = i*w*1 + "px";
        bar.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(1,211,97,0.6)";
        bar.style.opacity = "1.0";
        bar.style.width = w + "px";
        bar.style.height = h + "px";

        //var color1 = document.getElementById("histContainer");
        //var bar_color = document.createElement("div");
        //color1.appendChild(change);
        //bar.style.color = "rgba(1,211,97,0.6)";
    }
}



$(document).ready(function() {

$("#histContainer").bind("mouseover", function() {

    var shade = $("#histContainer").css("opacity");
    $("#histContainer").css("opacity", "0.7");

 $("#histContainer").bind("mouseout", function() {

   $("#histContainer").css("opacity", shade);


 });


    //$("histContainer").css("opacity", "0.4");


});

});
```

Comment: ID needs to be unique for the DOM element. If your code changes the opacity of many elements you should change their ids to something unique. Use class to bind the event and `this` to get the element that triggers the event.

Comment: I didn't get it??

Comment: Look at Steve T's answer

Comment: **Tip:** If you want to access a div tag using Javascript, you can use the DOM function **getElementsByTagName('div')[index]**. It will return a vector with all elements accordingly with the tag. To get a particular element, just change the index to 0,1,2...

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to all divs you would like to attach the hover event to, e.g.

```
<div class="histogram" id="histogram1"></div>
<div class="histogram" id="histogram2"></div>
<div class="histogram" id="histogram3"></div>
<div class="histogram" id="histogram4"></div>
```

Then use jquery's hover function to capture the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.histogram').hover(
      function() { // handler in
        $( this ).css('opacity', 0.7);
        // Additional actions (display info, etc.)
      }, function() { // handler out
        $( this ).css('opacity', 1);
        // Additional actions (hide info, etc.)
      }
  );
})
```

Comment: but the problem is, I am generating bars according to user input, so I cant decide on which bars to hover. After bars are generated, I hover on any one of them, and then change its opacity. Any hint for that??

Comment: Could you provide a sample for the HTML used to display the bars? Basically you just need to change the selector from ".histogram" to whatever applies to your case.

Comment: Its above in my question. Refer it.

Comment: Sorry didn't check the js code. In this case your selector would be `.myClass` .

Comment: Should work though. Try to attach the event AFTER creating the bars or use the `on` function to attach the event to all bars created afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use CSS for that? Give a equal class to your divs and then just do :

```
.your_div : hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

Comment: I am trying using mouseover function. Can you suggest using jquery method??

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for this.
CSS:

```
#hover-content {
    display:none;
}

#hover-me:hover #hover-content {
    display:block;
}
#hover-me:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

HMTL:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="hover-me">
        <span>Hover Me</span>
        <div id="hover-content">
            This content is visible only when you mouse hover the parent div and it has no transition.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this snippet if you want only backgroundto be opaque try `rgba()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.histogram').hover(
      function() { 
        $( this ).css('opacity', '0.7');
      }, function() {
        $( this ).css('opacity', '1');
      }
  );
})
```

```css
.histogram{
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
}
.red{
background-color:red;
}

.blue{
background-color:blue;
}

.green{
background-color:green;
}

.yell{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="histogram red" >1</div>
<div class="histogram blue">2</div>
<div class="histogram green">3</div>
<div class="histogram yell" >4</div>
```

Comment: Number of bars are being entered by user, AT RUN TIME. I cannot assign number of IDs for bars. It has to be iterated in a loop, I guess, to get IDs

Comment: i just entered the numbers for example

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript instead. It works.

```js
function draw() 
{
    var nums = document.getElementById("number").value.split(",");
    var w = 40;
    var factor = 20;
    var n_max =  Math.max.apply(parseInt, nums);
 var h_max = factor * n_max;
 
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= nums.length ; i++)
    {
        var x_cor = (i+1) * w;
        var h = factor * nums[i];       
        var change = document.getElementById("histContainer");
        var bar = document.createElement("div");
        bar.className = 'myClass';
        change.appendChild(bar);
        bar.style.position = "absolute";
        bar.style.top = (h_max - h) + "px";
        bar.style.left = i*w*1 + "px";
        bar.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(1,211,97,0.6)";
        bar.style.opacity = "1.0";
        bar.style.width = w + "px";
        bar.style.height = h + "px";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).on("mouseover",".myClass", function(index,el) {
  
  $(this).text($(this).index());
  var shade = $(this).css("opacity");
  $(this).css("opacity", "0.7");

   $(document).on("mouseout",".myClass", function() {

     $(this).css("opacity", shade);


   });

 }); 
});
```

Comment: I need to show the corresponding value of the bar(eg- I enter 4,6,8- bars corresponding to sizes are made, I need to display their sizes on mouseenter on bars). Any idea??

Comment: You can replace the `$(this).text($(this).index());` with `$(this).text(($(this).height())/20);`